CHROME based on-site remote control
I want to remotely manage the user's open browser window in order to support users on my website.
I simulated some events by transmitting click and keyup events over the socket, but due to browser policies, I do not have access to all events. For example, when I want to open the colorpicker, I receive a warning message.
    function triggerClickEvent(clickPosition) {
        var { x, y } = clickPosition;
        if (!window.clickEvent) {
            window.clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
                view: window,
                bubbles: true,
                button: 1,
                cancelable: true,
                clientX: x,
                clientY: y
            });
        } else {
            window.clickEvent.clientX = x;
            window.clickEvent.clientY = y;
        }
        document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        clickEvent.target.blur();
        clickEvent.target.focus();
        clickEvent.target.click();
    }

    function triggerKeyPressEvent(keyPress) {
        var keyPressEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': keyPress.key });
        document.dispatchEvent(keyPressEvent);
    }

How can I overcome these problems by obtaining the relevant User permissions?
